# Does WordPress expose a base URL in its JavaScript by default?

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

Usually when building sites I add something like this

```
var config = {
    basePath: '<?php echo BASE_PATH; ?>'
}
```

Simply so with my static JavaScript files I can do AJAX requests like

```
var request = config.basePath + 'ajax/get-something';
```

Does WordPress have a similar variable available to its JavaScript files by default, assuming I add my own scripts at the bottom of all WordPress included stuff?

Thanks

Comment: you could try relative urls, don't you? I guess you will need `get_options()` btw.

Comment: I use URL rewriting so I prefer to use a leading slash always when writing URLs.

Comment: Are you talking about the frontend or WP admin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the admin, there's a global variable `ajaxurl` that gives you the WP Ajax Url. I don't know if there's one for the front end built in, but you can do something like this to do it:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', create_function( '', '// echo your content here' ) );
```